# Installing database in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, cockroachdb

I'm trying to install CockroachDB with Rancher and getting some problems, showing:

```
FailedBinding (5)   14 sec ago  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

**How can this be solved?**

Here are the configurations in my local machine:

**PersistentVolumeClaim: datadir-cockroachdb-0**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-07T23:50:42Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: cockroachdb
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cockroachdb
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
      f:spec:
        f:accessModes: {}
        f:resources:
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:storage: {}
        f:volumeMode: {}
      f:status:
        f:phase: {}
    manager: k3s
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-07T23:50:41Z"
  name: datadir-cockroachdb-0
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "188922"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/datadir-cockroachdb-0
  uid: ef83d3c7-0309-44a8-b379-0134835d97a9
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending
```

**CockroachDB**

```yaml
clusterDomain: cluster.local
conf:
  attrs: []
  cache: 25%
  cluster-name: ''
  disable-cluster-name-verification: false
  http-port: 8080
  join: []
  locality: ''
  logtostderr: INFO
  max-disk-temp-storage: 0
  max-offset: 500ms
  max-sql-memory: 25%
  port: 26257
  single-node: false
  sql-audit-dir: ''
image:
  credentials: {}
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: cockroachdb/cockroach
  tag: v20.1.3
ingress:
  annotations: {}
  enabled: false
  hosts: []
  labels: {}
  paths:
    - /
  tls: []
init:
  affinity: {}
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: init
  nodeSelector: {}
  resources: {}
  tolerations: []
labels: {}
networkPolicy:
  enabled: false
  ingress:
    grpc: []
    http: []
service:
  discovery:
    annotations: {}
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
  ports:
    grpc:
      external:
        name: grpc
        port: 26257
      internal:
        name: grpc-internal
        port: 26257
    http:
      name: http
      port: 8080
  public:
    annotations: {}
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    type: ClusterIP
statefulset:
  annotations: {}
  args: []
  budget:
    maxUnavailable: 1
  env: []
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
  nodeAffinity: {}
  nodeSelector: {}
  podAffinity: {}
  podAntiAffinity:
    type: soft
    weight: 100
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  priorityClassName: ''
  replicas: 3
  resources: {}
  secretMounts: []
  tolerations: []
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
storage:
  hostPath: ''
  persistentVolume: volume1
    annotations: {}
    enabled: true
    labels: {}
    size: 1Gi
    storageClass: local-storage ''
tls:
  certs:
    clientRootSecret: cockroachdb-root
    nodeSecret: cockroachdb-node
    provided: false
    tlsSecret: false
  enabled: false
  init:
    image:
      credentials: {}
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      repository: cockroachdb/cockroach-k8s-request-cert
      tag: '0.4'
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
    name: ''
Storage: 1Gi
```

**PersistentVolume**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: '{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"type":"local"},"name":"volume1"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"capacity":{"storage":"10Gi"},"hostPath":{"path":"/data/volume1"}}}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-07T23:11:43Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  labels:
    type: local
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:phase: {}
    manager: k3s
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-07T23:11:43Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:type: {}
      f:spec:
        f:accessModes: {}
        f:capacity: {}
        f:hostPath:
          .: {}
          f:path: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: {}
        f:volumeMode: {}
    manager: kubectl
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-07T23:11:43Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:spec:
        f:capacity:
          f:storage: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-07T23:12:11Z"
  name: volume1
  resourceVersion: "173783"
  selfLink: /api/v1/persistentvolumes/volume1
  uid: 6e76984c-22cd-4219-9ff6-ba7f67c1ca72
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/volume1
    type: ""
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Available
```

**StorageClass**

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-07T23:29:17Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:provisioner: {}
      f:reclaimPolicy: {}
      f:volumeBindingMode: {}
    manager: rancher
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-07T23:29:17Z"
  name: local-storage
  resourceVersion: "180190"
  selfLink: /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/local-storage
  uid: 0a5f8b75-7fb5-4965-91ee-91b0a087339a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Answer (score 2):

With provided details looks like your storage class is missing on rancher.

Without storage class respective PVC won't get created so it's giving an error. Storage classes may change with cloud providers and also based on the requirement of the type of disk SSD, HDD.

You can get more idea : https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/volumes-and-storage/provisioning-new-storage/

check first your PV is available and after that check for storage class and PVC.

Comment: From the API: `https://localhost/v3/cluster/local/storageClasses/local-storage` it shows this https://gist.github.com/cyberquarks/987145ddf78be05873fe6de4d9fb30e0

Comment: @quarks rancher running on bare metal or which cloud provider ?

Comment: storageclass `local-path` Provisioner and this enables the ability to create persistent volume claims out of the box using local storage on the respective node only it wont create any disk if any cloud provider.

Comment: you can see list of all storage classes configuration might differ for local deployment and any cloud provider deployment or bare mental. https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/volumes-and-storage/

Comment: Just running rancher on my laptop for testing now

Comment: Also, despite how much I configure the YAML before installing cockroachdb from the catalog, it always have 100Gi in the persistence volume claim:

```
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

I'm trying to set it to just 1Gi for local testing

Comment: your pvc is 100 GB so due maybe dynamic provision it automatically creating it. try with deleting respective pvc and pv or with changing different name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227027/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-quarks).

Comment: Additionally, I tried this:
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/master/deploy/local-path-storage.yaml` but it is pending for a long time

```bash

kubectl -n local-path-storage get pod
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
local-path-provisioner-5b577f66ff-qp79p   0/1     Pending   0          10m
```

Comment: check issue by describing pod.

Comment: It shows `$ kubectl describe pod local-path-provisioner-5b577f66ff-qp79p
Error from server (NotFound): pods "local-path-provisioner-5b577f66ff-qp79p" not found` and from the dashboard: `0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.`

Comment: if you have not set taint and just want remove it this command :first  `kubectl get node` after that `kubectl taint nodes  <replace-node-name> node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure-`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was with Rancher this time (Thank you @Harsh Manvar for answering). If you have more questions about CockroachDB you can also join the CockroachDB community slack channel where you will find loads of experts who can answer your questions in a timely manner. (And be sure to join the #community channel also to have some FUN!) :)  https://go.crdb.dev/p/slack